# Wrapping variables in anonymous functions in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I'm a JS developer and use self-executing anonymous functions routinely to minimize pollution of the global scope.

ie: (JS)

```
(function(){
    var x = ...
})();
```

Is the same technique possible / advisable in PHP to minimize function / variable name clashes?

ie: (PHP)

```
(function(){

    $x = 2;

    function loop($a){
        ...
    }

    loop($x);

})();
```

Comment: Not exactly, but in PHP you can use namespace to avoid "global".

Comment: Or in other words, it is not required because of the namespace keyword

Comment: Hmm interesting solution. How would one switch from global scope to namespaced and back again?

Comment: Yes you can have anonymous functions that execute immediately in PHP. I've given an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid global pollution, use classes and an object oriented approach:
[See PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

To further avoid pollution, avoid static and global variables.

Closures like the one you have shown is used in Javascript is due to the fact that it (Javascript) is a prototype based language, with out properties (in the formative sense) normally shown in a OO based language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create anonymous functions in PHP that execute immediately without polluting the global namespace;

```
call_user_func(function() {
  $a = 'hi';
  echo $a;
});
```

The syntax isn't as pretty as the Javascript equivalent, but it does the same job. I find that construct very useful and use it often.

You may also return values like this;

```
$str = call_user_func(function() {
  $a = 'foo';
  return $a;
});

echo($str);   // foo
echo($a);     // Causes 'Undefined variable' error.
```